# Windows 7 Transfering File

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, my-documents

I use windows 7 and i was transfering (cut+paste) quite big file from flashdisk to my doccument. I accidentally press exit, so I transfer the rest of the file. I checked them in my doccument but some of the files are gone (most of them are the bigger file). I tried to use file recovery with another disk, but it was already filled with another file and it's not on the list I don't know where the file are now. Is there a way to get the files back? where are they?

Comment: What kind of document? Have you checked for file remnants in the same physical location as this "document"? More information is really necessary before any help could be offered.

Comment: It's a folder that contain lots of folder full with pictures each, and there are some remnants but only some folder with complete pictured, some folder are empty, and the rest of the folders are gone. @jrista

Comment: Well, given that the data was already overwritten with other data, I do not believe there is any way to recover. If you had not written additional data, you might have had a chance to recover.

Comment: I didn't add any data to it, so how do I recover it? @jrista

Comment: You said: "I tried to use file recovery with another disk, but it was already filled with another file". I interpreted that to mean you overwrote the files you copied with another file. Could you please clarify what you did, what the issue is, and what you have tried? Your question and comments are a little confusing.

Comment: I tried to use a bootup disk that has file restoration utilities that can be run from the disk which preserves more data. So it's like a list of data which has been deleted from my disk, but I already deleted too much data from my disk and the list is already full. I didn't do anything to the remnants. Sorry for confusing question. @jrista